# How to change multiple textViews to a certain day and hour, while the app is running

Tags: java, android, multithreading, timer, runnable

I'm kinda new here.
    So basically, I'm making an app that shows the restaurants available in a certain area and in my xml code I have multiple TextViews that inform if a restaurant is open or close.

I've tried to get the current day and hour in the onCreate method and chang the textView (like shown below).

```
TextView restaurant = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.openTag);
int hour = new Time (System.currentTimeMillis ()).getHour());
if (hour> = 14 && hour <= 19)
    restaurant.setText("OPEN");
```

But this is only the first time the app is started. Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: You can add a refresh button and when user click on that button recheck the time and than set text according to that. Or you can also use service or thread.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I want it to be automatically, not manually. I will check on threads and services!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after a little bit of trying and searching, I was able to find one solution that worked with my code. Here it goes a little sample of it:

```
private void updateTextView(ArrayList<Restaurant> restaurants, RestaurantAdapter itemsAdapter) {

                Date date = new Date();   // given date
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); // creates a new calendar instance
                calendar.setTime(date);   // assigns calendar to given date
                int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); // gets hour in 24h format
                int minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);        // gets hour in 12h format
                TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.openTag);
                if(hour>=21) {
                    restaurants.get(0).changeOpenTag("Closed");
                    itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                if (hour>= 9 && hour <= 15) {
                    title.setText("Lunch");
                }
                else {
                    title.setText("Dinner");
                }
    }
```

And on the onCreate method I added:

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (!isInterrupted()) {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                updateTextView(restaurants, itemsAdapter);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        };

        t.start();
```

I don't know if this is the most effective way of doing it, but at least it's working fine :D

Answer (score 0):

This might look like a lot of work on the UI thread for a task this simple.
You can have a timer which updates the TextView every second. This might be unnecessary overhead for your UI thread.

```
private void updateTextView() {
  Timer timer = new Timer();
  timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Your code goes here
        int hour = new Time (System.currentTimeMillis ()).getHour());
        if (hour> = 14 && hour <= 19)
          restaurant.setText("OPEN");
    }
  },0,1000); // Update TextView every second
}
```

And don't forget to call this function in your `onCreate()` function.

Comment: Alright man, thanks!! I will try your solution. Any other sugestion? I think I can add a listener? (Not sure). But I think it will make things faster

Comment: I'll let you know if I find another solution. And if you find this solution working, accept it to help others who have the same problem.

Comment: It actually didn't work. The app just simply crashes

Comment: Can you post the crash log?